# Algolia Autocomplete by calling Laravel endpoint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, algolia

Is it possible to use a Laravel Endpoint, to use as Algolia Autocomplete index?

Laravel Side:

```
Route::get('/search',function(){
      $query = request(q);
      return App\Contacts::search($query)->where('company_id',2)->raw();
}
```

Frontend

```
var index = 'http://laravel.app/search';

$('#contacts').autocomplete({ hint: false }, [
        {
            source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(index, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
            displayKey: 'name',
            templates: {
                dropdownMenu: '#my-custom-menu-template',
                footer: '<div class="branding">Powered by <img src="https://www.algolia.com/static_assets/images/press/downloads/algolia-logo-light.svg" /></div>',
                suggestion: function(suggestion) {
                    return suggestion._highlightResult.iata.value + ' '+ suggestion._highlightResult.name.value ;
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy change to change the endpoint in autocomplete.js I think. It will require to modify the library.

Can I ask why you want to do this? It's not recommended to call your backend, it's best to call Algolia directly. The main reason to use Algolia in the backend is to integrate it quickly and not use frontend libraries like autocomplete.js or InstantSearch.js. Since you're willing to use them, you should call Algolia directly. It will save a lot of network latency and offload your server.

Each time someone search, the query will be:

**browser -> Algolia -> browser**

instead of

**browser -> server -> Algolia -> server -> browser**

Comment: The UI sucks big time, and I've been struggling to fix them. And I had more filters to add. None the less, that was my guess as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing Algolias API, I would use Curl or Guzzle to send a GET request (or whatever they want) to there API, transform the respond according to what the autocomplete JS is expecting and and push it back to the frontend.